# How to improve efficiency in while loop by pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, distance, coordinate

I am a new python er. in my job, I open deal mass of data. So I begin to study python to improve the efficiency. 
The first small trial is that: finding the nearest distance between two coordinates.
 I have two files, one is named as "book.csv", the other is named as "macro.csv".[file content screen shot][1]

book.csv has three column: BookName, Longitude,Latitude; macro.csv has threed column: MacroName, Longitude,Latitude.
 the trial purpose is to find the nearest Macro to each book. I try to use pandas to finish this trial, now I can get the right result, but the efficiency is a little low, when I have a 1500 book and 200 macro, **it will take about 15 second.** 
please to help whether I can improve the efficiency. thx the following is my trial code:

```
#import pandas lib
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import pandas as pd

#import geopy lib, to calculate the distance between two poins
import geopy.distance

#def func, to calculate the distance, input parameter: two points coordinates(Lat,Lon),return m
def dist(coord1,coord2):
        return geopy.distance.vincenty(coord1, coord2).m

#def func, to find the nearest result: including MacroName and distance
def find_nearest_macro(df_macro,df_book):
    #Get column content from dataframe to series
    # Macro
    s_macro_name = df_macro["MacroName"]
    s_macro_Lat = df_macro["Latitude"]
    s_macro_Lon = df_macro["Longitude"]
    # Book
    s_book_name = df_book["BookName"]
    s_book_Lat = df_book["Latitude"]
    s_book_Lon = df_book["Longitude"]

    #def a empty list, used to append nearest result
    nearest_macro = []
    nearest_dist = []

    #Loop through each book
    ibook = 0
    while ibook < len(s_book_name):
        #Give initial value to result
        nearest_macro_name = s_macro_name[0]
        nearest_macro_dist = dist((s_book_Lat[0],s_book_Lon[0]), (s_macro_Lat[0],s_macro_Lon[0]))

        #Get the coordinate of the x book
        book_coord = (s_book_Lat[ibook],s_book_Lon[ibook])

        #Loop through each Macro, Reset the loop variable
        imacro = 1
        while imacro < len(s_macro_name):
            # Get the coordinate of the x Macro
            macro_cood = (s_macro_Lat[imacro],s_macro_Lon[imacro])
            #Calculate the distance between book and macro
            tempd = dist(book_coord,macro_cood)
            #if distance more close
            if tempd < nearest_macro_dist:
                #Update the result
                nearest_macro_dist = tempd
                nearest_macro_name = s_macro_name[imacro]
            #Increments the loop variable
            imacro = imacro + 1
        #Loop over each book, append the nearest to the result
        nearest_macro.append(nearest_macro_name)
        nearest_dist.append(nearest_macro_dist)
        # Increments the loop variable
        ibook = ibook + 1
    #return nearest macro name and distance(by tuple way can return 2 results
    return (nearest_macro,nearest_dist)

# Assign the filename:
file_macro = '.\\TestFile\\Macro.csv'
file_book = '.\\TestFile\\Book.csv'

#read content from csv to dataframe
df_macro = pd.read_csv(file_macro)
df_book = pd.read_csv(file_book)

#find the nearest macro name and distance
t_nearest_result = find_nearest_macro(df_macro,df_book)

#create a new series, convert list to Series
s_nearest_marco_name =  Series(t_nearest_result[0])
s_nearest_macro_dist = Series(t_nearest_result[1])

#insert the new Series to dataframe
df_book["NearestMacro"] = s_nearest_marco_name
df_book["NearestDist"] = s_nearest_macro_dist
print(df_book.head())

# write the new df_book to a new csv file
df_book.to_csv('.\\TestFile\\nearest.csv')
```

Comment: For a better response from the SO community, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly.